# Uncaught TypeError: weather is undefined in React + weatherbit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, weather-api

I'm working with react and weatherbit api , when i call my data array i have an error with weather object , here is my code ...

```
import React from "react";

const CityWeather = ({data, cityName}) => {
    const {weather, app_temp, wind_spd, temp} = data
    return (
        <div className="cityWeather">
            <div className="cityWeatherPrincipalData">
                <h2 id="city">{cityName}</h2>
                <h4 id="cityWeatherTemperatureNow">{temp}</h4>
                <div id="cityWeatherTemperatureMaxMin">
                    <h4>{app_temp}</h4>
                </div>
                <div id="cityWeatherWind">
                    <h4 id="cityWeatherWind">{wind_spd}</h4>
                </div>
                <h2 id="cityWeatherStateSky">{weather.description}</h2>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default CityWeather
```

and here is my api url in another component...

```
        useEffect(() => {
        if(!town)return;
        let url = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=${town.latitud}&lon=${town.longitud}&key={APIKEY}1&include=minutely`;
        api.get(url).then((res)=>{
            if(!res.err){
                setData(res);
                console.log(res)
            }
        })
```

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: So sounds like when the component first loads the data is not set so it errors out. Add a check to see if the data is loaded before displaying it.

Comment: weather is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a $ before {APIKEY}. Try doing this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!town) return;
  let url = `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?lat=${town.latitud}&lon=${town.longitud}&key=${APIKEY}1&include=minutely`;
  api.get(url).then((res)=>{
  if(!res.err){
    setData(res);
    console.log(res)
  }
})
```

Comment: Ok ... its doesnt works but the problem is how i call the elements in the object , how i can call the elements ? this is the array ...  Object { count: 1, data: (1) […], minutely: (60) […] }
​
count: 1
​
data: Array [ {…} ]
​​
0: Object { rh: 61, pod: "d", lon: -70.65, … }
​​​
app_temp: 10
​​​
aqi: 212
​​​
city_name: "Santiago"
​​​
clouds: 80
​​​
country_code: "CL"
​​​
datetime: "2022-07-14:20"
​​​
dewpt: 2.8
​​​
dhi: 71.43
​​​
lat: -33.44
​​​
lon: -70.65
weather: Object { icon: "c03d", code: 803, description: "Broken clouds" }
<prototype>: Object { … }